# Text Transform in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm trying to get

```
text transform: lowercase;
```

work with all versions of outlook, yet it's having no effect on the text.

I've checked and outlook does support this property.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-transform:lowercase">Enter</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Older versions of outlook do not support `text-transform`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)